# how do I get Rounded Corners to work on a ddblock in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to make the borders of a dd-block that I am using round. They are round in Firefox 5.0, but anything earlier than that, or in any other browser, it doesn't work. I have the CurvyCorners module installed, and I have the CSS set up to make it round. the problem is, that in chrome, only the header is round, and nothing else. and in Internet explorer, everything is round, except the dd-block, making it look like the dd-block is overlapping, and going over and past the corners of the region that it is in (being the Content region).
here is a copy of the CSS that is supposed to be making it round (I used 4 different classes/blocks at the same time just for a single dd-block, and it still won't work!):

```
#block-ddblock-7 {
    margin-left: -10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}

#block-ddblock-7 .slider {
     border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    width: 553px;
    height: 332px;
}

#ddblock-container clearfix ddblock-processed .inner {
     border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px 20px;
    width: 553px;
    height: 332px;
}

.slider ddblock-processed  {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;

    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;

    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;

    -o-border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    -o-border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;
}
```

what is it that I am doing wrong?

this is a picture of basically what it looks like. the part in blue is the "Content" region, and the part in orange is the ddblock:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've used ddblock before with round corners.   I was able to do it all, across every browser, with the [csspie](http://drupal.org/project/css3pie) module.

But atlas you are using CurvyCorners. With this [demo](http://www.curvycorners.net/includes/examples/demo4.html), they are only using

```
.myBox {
    ....
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    ...
}
```

nothing to do with o-border, webkit-border, khtml-border, -moz-border, border-top-right etc.  half of these are browser specific  (ie -moz-border is for firefox only).

Comment: Just tried that module. It didn't make any difference. is there anything specific that I have to do with that, that I haven't already put in that css (or do I need to delete something to make it work)?

Comment: I looked at the demo, and that works for text, but it doesn't seem to work for a ddblock on anything except firefox 5.

Comment: sorry need to see it, not enough information

Comment: being that the client wants confidentiality, I can't show you the actual site, but I updated the question to have a picture of what the basic idea of what it looks like is.

Comment: Did you manage to get this sorted? @iStryker any advice you could provide to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60914/css3pie-not-working-in-ie